# it is planned going to Stage 4.x?

Tags: ros, simulation, stageros, stage, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is somebody or organization working on this?

Stage 4.x has interesting features which are not properly working in Stage 3.2.2, for instance I'm interested on set the update interval of models like sensors or actuators.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12838/it-is-planned-going-to-stage-4.x?/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2012-02-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS fuerte (expected release in March 2012) will have Stage 4.X.X, in case you are looking to relate Stage 3 and Stage 4 then have a look here, http://blog.aus10.org/?p=125.

**UPDATE** : ROS fuerte will have Stage 4.1.1

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2012-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1